# positioning multiple images dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, image, positioning, dreamweaver

I', new to dreamweaver and building websites period, but one thing that has got me baffled is positioning multiple images.

Example:  I add an image to the website and position it using the position tool/code. It works out well. Then I go to add another image and when I go to position it the image I placed first will move with it, as if they are linked some how.

So the question is how can I position them separately so they don't move together when I use the position tool?

Comment: I started using Dreamweaver about a year ago, and slowly learned that using the WYSIWYG "half" of the screen was not trivial, and often more difficult than using the "code" side of the screen. Slowly I moved to only using the "code" side and only used DW for FTP (I've switched to Filezilla). I'd suggest you learn about placement of images based on pure HTML/CSS. After you get the hang of it, it's pretty easy. Can you describe how you want the images positioned?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use FrontPage or something similar. Dreamweaver is in some respects  what photoshop is for graphics.  It is more for advanced users who will position images correctly using custom CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the source code I'd recommend getting to grips with CSS. Images require position, if this be adding the 'display' or 'position' attributes or even using 'floats'.

Visual editors like the one you're describing are normally pretty limited in the way you can position images like you require. I suppose you could always create the website using tables. Most visual editors such as Dreamweaver will give you full control over these and you can position them correctly into the correct table rows/cells.